# TxPool size on public BSC node

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, bsc, txpool

Something happened to BSC public node(https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/), and I am confused.

I usually call this BSC public node to get block transactions and content of txpool. Average number of transactions that txpool contained was around 500 , but last fey days I receive from 0 to 30 transactions. Since BSC is recording ATH number of transactions, txpool should contain more transactions than ever, right? I don't understand what is going on? Does anybody know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should your private node with websocket connection to subscribe the Txpool message. That will behave as what you expect.